# Lua: How to parse http post result?

Tags: http, lua, http-post

I am writing a http client in lua to consume a rest web service.
The webservice result should be in this json format:

```
{
   "code": "123456789",
   "valid_until": "09/09/2020"
}
```

This is my lua script:

```
param_1 = arg[1];
param_2 = arg[2];

http = require("socket.http");
ltn12 = require("ltn12");
path = "http://www.url.com:8080/api/";
body = [[ {"number_id":"b8ce37fb-2061-4aea-975b-57a8e2d355ce","param_1":"]]..param_1..[[","param_2":"]]..param_2..[["} ]];
response_body = { }
res, code, response_haders, status = http.request {
    url = path,
    method = "POST",
    headers =
    {
        ["X-Access-Key"] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        ["Content-Type"] = "application/json",
        ["Content-Length"] = body:len()
    },
    source = ltn12.source.string(body),
}
print("res:"..res);
print("code:"..code);
print("status:"..status);
```

when I run my script this is the results I got:

```
res:1
code:201
statusHTTP/1.0 201 CREATED
```

Why I getting 1 as result, What should I do to parse the result?

Comment: What's the problem with `1`?  The doc says `In case of failure, the function returns nil followed by an error message. If successful, the simple form returns the response body as a string, followed by the response status code, the response headers and the response status line. The generic function returns the same information, except the first return value is just the number 1 (the body goes to the sink). `

Comment: I don't understand in my case what should i do?

Comment: Just ignore this `1`.  It's not C.  Returned `1` does not mean an error.  The response body should be read from the sink.

Comment: I know it's not a problem, I just want to parse the result of my http post result that should be `{"code": "123456789", "valid_until": "09/09/2020"}`

Comment: `valid_until` is probably in `response_haders`

Comment: you forgot  `sink = ltn12.sink.table(response_body) ` in  `http.request`, and then result will be in table `response_body`